# Is there any advantage to working within virtualenvs on single purpose EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, virtualenv, python-venv

It seems redundant to me since I created the EC2 solely for the purpose of working on this specific project. Why do I need to create another virtual environment on top of that?

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted on this? Please let me know so I can modify

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't need to do that. But there are some reasons, most notably the ability to pip install as a non-root user.